# Inserting proper values between two arrays in the same ms excel/ open office cals, with duplicates

Tags: excel, function, calc

Good evening!

I'd like to ask for a help with propably simple matter that I've been trying to solve today.

I've got this calc sheet:

[image]

And I am trying to, with a help of a proper Function, copy the grades that were given on the 31 of may, from the right array to the left one.( just the ones from 31 may )

I've tried several functions: Lookup, Vlookup, XLookup, Index and Match but I seem to fail the job...
The problem might be that there are duplicates within the surname and name on both of the arrays and of course the fact that I have to copy only the grade from 31 may.
I am powerless. If anyone has any new lead, any help would be appreaciated. Thank you in advance.
Thomas.

Comment: In the table on the right, do you want a list of ALL the names, or just the names that had a grade on May 31?

Comment: In the table on the LEFT, I want to list/copy/instert just the grades that are listed IN the RIGHT array, and only from  the 31 may.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D5: =IFERROR(FILTER(L:L,(H:H=C5)*(I:I=B5)*(J:J="may")*(K:K=31)),"")
```

*and fill down*

[image]

Comment: For my example I am using your modified function: =iferror(filter(l:l,(h:h=B5)*(i:i=C5)*(j:j="maj")*(k:k=31)),"") , because my columns 'name and 'surname' correspond to different letters and ofc i use the word 'maj'. I put the command into the D5 field and still i get and error 501. I am using open office calc.

Comment: @TomaszWąsowicz Your question has an **Excel** tag and, as you can see from the screenshot, my solution works in Excel. I probably can't help you with OO.  What does error 501 mean in OO?  Possibly you don't have the one of the functions.

Comment: Mhm I was foolish to believe both programs use similar functions. I'll install MS Office and check your sollution. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've tried using the said above formule, I am still getting an error on MSExcel: https://ibb.co/fXc9rh1

Comment: @TomaszWąsowicz Are your windows regional settings set to use a comma or the semicolon for the separator.  If the latter, you need to edit the formula.

Comment: The separation with a semicolon instead of a coma was the issue that was making the formula to fail ( My regional settings use a semicolon). It all works now. Of course I understand the formula now, but I'd never pick it in the first place. I still have so much to learn. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((H:H=A2)*(I:I=B2)*(J:J=$B$1)*(K:K=$C$1)*L:L)
```

Note that B1 = *Maj* and C1 = *31*. I think it would be easier to have one date - a true date (you may like to read up about dates in Excel). You can display a true date in any ay you want, including "mmm" format in one cell an "dd" format in another, but columns K and L should have the same value, meaning the same date, thereby simplifying the formula and probably a lot of other work around your table.

Comment: The structure of the calc sheet was something I didn't construct myself, I just need to work with what I have, I accept all of the lead, it's a valuable info. I just don't understand one simple thing: what's the cell I should use the formula to be tested ?

Comment: I've used the function you wrote, it sadly returns a NAME error. I am using the open office calc.

Comment: So, now you learn the difference between CALC and Excel. On your next question make sure to check the correct tags.